# Objective C - ERROR: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting an error when trying to call a method.

The method

```
- (void)setSpeed:(GLKVector2)newSpeed{  //Error message (see title) points to here
    self.speed = GLKVector2Make(newSpeed.x, newSpeed.y);
}
```

The call

```
[self setSpeed:GLKVector2Make(0, 0)];
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is an infinite loop going on. When you call `self.speed = ...`, it calls the setter method `- (void)setSpeed:(GLKVector2)newSpeed;`, which then calls `self.speed = ...`. Replacing  `self.speed = ...` with  `_speed = ...` will fix the error.

Comment: did I coincidentally choose a method name that already exists?

Comment: Yes. The properties (`self.speed`) auto-generate 2 methods: A **Getter** (`- (GLKVector2)speed;`), and a **Setter** (`- (void)setSpeed:(GLKVector2)speed;`). You accidentally overwrote the **Setter** method.

Answer (score 10):

try write

```
_speed = GLKVector2Make(newSpeed.x, newSpeed.y);
```

or

```
speed = GLKVector2Make(newSpeed.x, newSpeed.y);
```

instead of

```
self.speed = GLKVector2Make(newSpeed.x, newSpeed.y);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. What is the difference between self.var and _var?

Comment: self.var take value of property var,  _var - take value of the variable directly

Answer (score 4):

`self.speed=` sets the `speed` property using whatever accessor is chosen for it. the default name for the setter of a property named "speed" will be `setSpeed:`. This is the method you're using, it just keeps calling itself over and over and never stopping. You want to set the instance variable directly (if you just have an `@property` declaration and don't have an explicit `@synthesize`, this will be `_speed`).